# Output an Animated Trigonometry Circle

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, animation, trigonometry

I want you to write a program that outputs a trigonometry circle like the one below. I also want you to animate this circle, having the sine line move along the circumference with the other lines move around it. **The minimum number of *unique* frames is 5. Any lower and your entry will not be counted.**

[image: Trig circle]

The lines you will need are:

- Sine (Both)
- Cosine (Both)
- Secant
- Cosecant
- Tangent
- Cotangent
- OA (on diagram)

### Edit: No longer a limit

<strike>This is a code golf challenge, but I want you to get your code to **below** my code which is written in BBC BASIC.</strike>

*Note:* I will remove this requirement if the challenge is too hard.

#### My code: BBC BASIC - 185 bytes, 232 characters (Thanks Steve)

```
a=0:REPEAT:CLS:a+=0.005:CIRCLE600,500,300:s=300*SIN(a)+500:c=300*COS(a)+600:sc=300*1/COS(a)+600:cs=300*1/SIN(a)+500:MOVE600,500:DRAWc,s:DRAWc,500:DRAW600,500:DRAWsc,500:DRAWc,s:MOVE600,500:DRAW600,cs:DRAWc,s:DRAW600,s:WAIT 1:UNTIL0
```

[image: Trig Circle]

Comment: An image or gif of what your code produces would be very helpful.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Added

Comment: I count ASCII 232 characters there, though with tokenisation it probably is 185 bytes. Watch out for that byte counter on BBC Basic for Windows. I usually post as an ASCII count. Your code is probabably golfable down below 185 ASCII characters with VDU's though.

Comment: And when the tangent or cotangent are infinite, what should be drawn? Also, what does "output" mean? Can a program write a gif or video file, or should it output in real time on a canvas?

Comment: @PeterTaylor When tan and cot are infinite, you could draw it to a *very long* length. Regarding the format of the output, it can be anything.

Comment: Dead link, perhaps?

Comment: @sergiol I've updated it now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Mathematica, 142 bytes

```
Graphics[{Circle[],Line/@{{{c=Cos@t,0},{c,s=Sin@t},{0,s}},{{0,0},{1/c,0},{0,1/s},{0,0},{c,s}}},},PlotRange->{r={-2,2},r}]~Animate~{t,0.01,2Pi}
```

I'm plotting for angles between `0.01` and `2π` which conveniently skips any angles where one of the lines would become actually infinite. You can make a GIF from it by replacing `Animate` with `Table`, adding a step width of `0.1` say and then using `Export` on the result:

[image]

So I got a bit bored and thought I'd give the full-blown thing a go (with all lines and colours). I omitted the labels, because they are really annoying to position and just clutter everything up.

```
Animate[
  c = Cos@t;
  s = Sin@t;
  h = Sign@c;
  v = Sign@s;
  i = .1 h;
  j = .1 v;
  Graphics[{
    Thick,
    Circle[],
    Line /@ {{{c, -s}, {0, 0}, {c, s}}, {{-i, 0}, {-i, j}, {0, 
        j}}, {{-i + c, 0}, {-i + c, j}, {c, j}}, {{c - .1 s, 
        s + .1 c}, {1.1 c - .1 s, 1.1 s + .1 c}, 1.1 {c, s}}},
    Circle[{0, 0}, 0.1, {t, Round[t, Pi]}],
    Blue,
    Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {c, 0}}, {{0, s}, {c, s}}},
    Red,
    Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {0, s}}, {{c, 0}, {c, s}}},
    Darker@Green,
    Line[{{c, 0}, {h, 0}}],
    Cyan,
    Line[{{0, s}, {0, v}}],
    Lighter@Lighter@Magenta,
    Line[{{h, 0}, {1/c, 0}}],
    Darker@Darker@Green,
    Line[{{0, v}, {0, 1/s}}],
    Orange,
    Line[{{0, 1/s}, {c, s}}],
    Lighter@Brown,
    Line[{{1/c, 0}, {c, s}}],
    Gray,
    Line[{{c, 0}, {c, -s}}],
    Lighter@Gray,
    Line[{{c, s}, {h, 0}}],
    Lighter@Pink,
    Line /@ {{{-.45 h, 0}, {-.55 h, 0}}, {{-.45 h, 1/s}, {-.55 h, 
        1/s}}},
    Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}],
    Arrow[{{-.5 h, 0}, {-.5 h, 1/s}}],
    Darker@Cyan,
    Line /@ {{{0, -.45 v}, {0, -.55 v}}, {{1/c, -.45 v}, {1/
         c, -.55 v}}},
    Arrow[{{0, -.5 v}, {1/c, -.5 v}}],
    Dashed,
    Black,
    Line[{{c, s}, 1.3 {c, s}}],
    Lighter@Pink,
    Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {-.5 h, 0}}, {{0, 1/s}, {-.5 h, 1/s}}},
    Darker@Cyan,
    Line /@ {{{0, 0}, {0, -.5 v}}, {{1/c, 0}, {1/c, -.5 v}}}
    }, PlotRange -> {r = {-2, 2}, r}],
  {t, 0.01, 2 Pi}
  ];
```

Enjoy!

[image]

And because this is still a code-golf question I golfed this down as well, to see how short I could get it. Currently, **719 bytes**:

```
Graphics[{Thick,Arrowheads@{-.05,.05},(z=Circle)[],(n=Line)/@{{p={c=Cos@t,s=Sin@t},o={0,0},{c,-s}},{-{i=.1(h=Sign@c),0},{-i,j=.1(v=Sign@s)},{0,j}},{{-i+c,0},{-i+c,j},{c,j}},{p+(q={-.1s,.1c}),1.1p+q,1.1p}},z[o,0.1,{t,Round[t,Pi]}],{e=Dashed,n[{p,1.3p}]},Blue,n/@{{o,a={c,0}},{b={0,s},p}},Red,n/@{{o,b},{a,p}},g=(d=Darker)@Green,n@{a,{h,0}},y=Cyan,n@{b,{0,v}},(l=Lighter)@l@Magenta,n@{{h,0},f={1/c,0}},d@g,n@{{0,v},u={0,1/s}},Orange,n@{u,p},l@Brown,n@{f,p},r=Gray,n@{a,{c,-s}},l@r,n@{p,{h,0}},l@Pink,n/@{q={{-.45h,0},{-.55h,0}},{u,u}+q},Arrow@{q={-.5h,0},u+q},{e,n/@{{o,q},{u,u+q}}},d@y,n/@{q={{0,-.45v},{0,-.55v}},{f,f}+q},Arrow@{q={0,-.5v},f+q},{e,n/@{{o,q},{f,f+q}}}},PlotRange->{r={-2,2},r}]~Animate~{t,0.01,2Pi,0.05}
```

Comment: Nice, the colours are great!

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 125 bytes

```apl
P5.size←2⌿300
t←0
g←P5.G
z←0 0
P5.draw←{g.bg¯1
g.circle 3⌿90
g.ln a←90×1+z,2 1○t
g.rect a
g.ln 90×1+z,(÷2○t),z,z,⍨÷1○t
t+←.1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P8BUrzizKvVR2wSjRz37jQ0MuEqAbAOudCAJlHPnqgJxFQy4gJyUosRyIK86XS8p/dB6Q650veTMouScVAVjoFZLoB69nDyFRKAKS4PD0w21q3SMFAwfTe8uAUoUpSaXKCRCVMBkNQ5vNwJJa@pUAeGj3hWHt0OUl2gDzdAzrP3/HwA)

Displays it at the top left corner:

[image]

### Explanation

`P5.size←2⌿300` make a 300x300 canvas

`t←0` set angle \$\theta=0.\$

`g←P5.G` shorten drawing namespace

`z←0 0` save [0,0] in `z`

`P5.draw←{` Do the following repeatedly:

`g.bg¯1` Draw a white background

`g.circle 3⌿90` draw a circle of radius 90 at \$(90, 90)\$

`g.ln a←90×1+z,2 1○t` Line from \$(90,90)\$ to \$(90cos\theta, 90sin\theta)\$ for angle

`g.rect a` rectangle using the same coordinates

`g.ln 90×1+z,(÷2○t),z,z,⍨÷1○t` triangle with the points \$(90, 90),(90,90/cos\theta),(90/sin\theta,90)\$

`t+←.1` increment angle \$\theta\$